# Mainapp does not start

Tags: java, eclipse, scenebuilder

I need to debug my main app and I can't find the error. The app doesn't start the `PersonOverviewController`. Where do I need to fix this issue, in the fmxl=

Messages in the Control

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/Users/stefanhegetschweiler/Documents/Weiterbildung/FH/Programmierung/Projekt/17.08.2014/VokabularTrainer/bin/ch/makery/address/view/PersonOverview.fxml

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2617)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2587)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
at ch.makery.address.MainApp.showPersonOverview(MainApp.java:162)
at ch.makery.address.MainApp.start(MainApp.java:120)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$8.run(LauncherImpl.java:837)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$7.run(PlatformImpl.java:335)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:301)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:298)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6.run(PlatformImpl.java:298)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

`PersonOverviewController`:

```
package ch.makery.address.view;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;

import org.controlsfx.dialog.Dialogs;

import ch.makery.address.MainApp;
import ch.makery.address.model.Person;

public class PersonOverviewController {
    @FXML
    private TableView<Person> personTable;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Person, String> firstNameColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Person, String> lastNameColumn;

    @FXML
    private Label firstNameLabel;
    @FXML
    private Label lastNameLabel;
    @FXML


    // Reference to the main application.
    private MainApp mainApp;

    /**
     * The constructor.
     * The constructor is called before the initialize() method.
     */
    public PersonOverviewController() {
    }

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class. This method is automatically called
     * after the fxml file has been loaded.
     */
    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        // Initialize the person table with the two columns.
        firstNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(
                cellData -> cellData.getValue().firstNameProperty());
        lastNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(
                cellData -> cellData.getValue().lastNameProperty());

        // Clear person details.
        showPersonDetails(null);

        // Listen for selection changes and show the person details when changed.
        personTable.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(
                (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> showPersonDetails(newValue));
    }

    /**
     * Is called by the main application to give a reference back to itself.
     * 
     * @param mainApp
     */
    public void setMainApp(MainApp mainApp) {
        this.mainApp = mainApp;

        // Add observable list data to the table
        personTable.setItems(mainApp.getPersonData());
    }

    /**
     * Fills all text fields to show details about the person.
     * If the specified person is null, all text fields are cleared.
     * 
     * @param person the person or null
     */
    private void showPersonDetails(Person person) {
        if (person != null) {
            // Fill the labels with info from the person object.
            firstNameLabel.setText(person.getFirstName());
            lastNameLabel.setText(person.getSecondEnglish());

        } else {
            // Person is null, remove all the text.
            firstNameLabel.setText("");
            lastNameLabel.setText("");

        }
    }

    /**
     * Called when the user clicks on the delete button.
     */
    @FXML
    private void handleDeletePerson() {
        int selectedIndex = personTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
        if (selectedIndex >= 0) {
            personTable.getItems().remove(selectedIndex);
        } else {
            // Nothing selected.
            Dialogs.create()
                .title("No Selection")
                .masthead("No word selected")
                .message("Please select a word in the table.")
                .showWarning();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Called when the user clicks the new button. Opens a dialog to edit
     * details for a new person.
     */
    @FXML
    private void handleNewPerson() {
        Person tempPerson = new Person();
        boolean okClicked = mainApp.showPersonEditDialog(tempPerson);
        if (okClicked) {
            mainApp.getPersonData().add(tempPerson);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Called when the user clicks the edit button. Opens a dialog to edit
     * details for the selected person.
     */
    @FXML
    private void handleEditPerson() {
        Person selectedPerson = personTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        if (selectedPerson != null) {
            boolean okClicked = mainApp.showPersonEditDialog(selectedPerson);
            if (okClicked) {
                showPersonDetails(selectedPerson);
            }

        } else {
            // Nothing selected.
            Dialogs.create()
                .title("No Selection")
                .masthead("No word selected")
                .message("Please select a word in the table.")
                .showWarning();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Called when the user clicks the show Answer button. Opens a dialog to edit
     * details for the selected person.
     */
    @FXML
    private void handleAnswer() {
        Person selectedPerson = personTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        if (selectedPerson != null) {
            boolean okClicked = mainApp.showAnswerDialog(selectedPerson);
            if (okClicked) {
                showPersonDetails(selectedPerson);
            }

        } else {
            // Nothing selected.
            Dialogs.create()
                .title("No Selection")
                .masthead("No word selected")
                .message("Please select a word in the table.")
                .showWarning();
        }
    }
        /**
         * Called when the user clicks on the train english button.
         */
        @FXML
        private void handleTrainEnglish() {
            Person selectedPerson = personTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
            if (selectedPerson != null) {
                boolean okClicked = mainApp.showEnglishTrainDialog(selectedPerson);
                if (okClicked) {
                    showPersonDetails(selectedPerson);
                }

            } else {
                // Nothing selected.
                Dialogs.create()
                    .title("No Selection")
                    .masthead("No word selected")
                    .message("Please select a word in the table.")
                    .showWarning();
            }
        }
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried changing `private void initialize()` to `public void initialize()`?

Comment: Thanks you, I restored my version and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in contrast to e.g. Spring, FXML will not change the access-level of the methods it calls by reflection. That means you need to make your `initialize()`-method public so it can be called by `javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader`.